# Building SQL SELECT statement within EXCEL

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build SQL statements within excel.

Sample:

[image]

I am trying to build sql statement, but wanted to only add the column when there is a value in the DIM columns. So the SQL looks neat without any syntax error when executed in SQL.

Here how can I eliminate the extra commas before the "from" keyword?

Used this to generate those statements.

```
="SELECT RET_ID,RET_NM, "&C2&","&D2&","&E2&","&F2&" FROMTABLEX"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach which shall work for all versions of Excel

`="SELECT RET_ID,RET_NM,"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2)," ",",")&" FROMTABLEX"`

You can add any number of columns inside `TRIM()`.

Comment: Note that should any of the column names have spaces in them (in which case they would have to be escaped), this answer might not generate the correct select statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen valid observation!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Office 2019, the [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function is very helpful here, because it lets you build a CSV string with optional components:

```
="SELECT RET_ID, RET_NM, "&TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, C2, D2, E2, F2)&" FROM TABLEX"
```

If you are using an earlier version of Excel, you can still pull off what you want, by using `IF()` combined with `CONCATENATE()`, but the logic is more verbose.

Comment: Or a little shorter: `="SELECT RET_ID, RET_NM, "&TEXTJOIN(", ",1,C2:F2)&" FROM TABLEX"`