# Excel Formula help on getting the syntax right

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula

Excel Version: 2016

I've asked the main question here, this is the extension of that question.

[Building SQL SELECT statement within EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788842/building-sql-select-statement-within-excel/61789170#61789170)
[image]

I need to extend the logic for all the columns whenever there is a value in that in the sql "AND" clause as well.

eg. **AND TAB1.COLUMNA = TAB2.TCOLUMNA AND TAB1.COLUMNB = TAB2.COLUMNB** and so on, only if there is a value in the DIM columns.

I am not sure how to embed it dynamically using the SUBSTITUTE and TRIM functions.

Edit: Formula

```
="select * from (SELECT RET_ID,RET_NM,"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2)," ",",")&" FROM 
TABLEX ORDER BY "&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2)," ",",")&") TAB1 FULL OUTER JOIN   (SELECT RET_ID,RET_NM,"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2)," ",",")&" FROM 
TABLEX ORDER BY "&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2)," ",",")&") TAB2 ON TAB1.RET_ID = TAB2.RET_ID AND TAB1.RET_NM = TAB2.RET_NM  "
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, By this piece of code

```
"&IF(LEN(D2)>0,CONCATENATE("AND COALESCE(TAB1.",D2,",'')","="," COALESCE(TAB2.",D2,",'')"),"")&"
```